# using left join returns multiple values

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join

I have used below query where its returns me correct output. I would like to expand this query further more and I have no idea how can I do this.

I have two table **history_query** and **tb_MA**

> History_query Table schema

```
ID     Verantwortlich             Role                           Error_text 
     [Contain UserName]      (Can be User_name Or Catagories)      

15      US1                   10 ENG-PL                           zxcv
7                                US3                              wxyz
10      US3                                                        xyz
20      US2                     07 ROB                            lekd
9                                 US1                              wer
20                            10 ENG-PL                           zlcv
```

> TB_MA TAble Schema

```
UserName              Team             Skills 
 US1               10 ENG-PL
 US2               07 ROB
 US3               10 ENG-PL
```

In my Access Form I have a combobox in which User can select category like '10 ENG-PL'.

Based on this value First of all I would like to find how many user are there from TB_MA, than find all data from history_query that Username is present in column 'Verantwortlich' or in column 'Role' or Categories is present '10 ENG-PL'

Based on above table data

> Final Output What I need

```
ID   Verantwortlich             Role                           Error_text 

15      US1                   10 ENG-PL                           zxcv
7                                US3                              wxyz
10      US3                                                        xyz
9                                US1                               wer
20                            10 ENG-PL                           zlcv
```

query which i have used is

```
SELECT *
FROM history_query  left JOIN tb_MA ON history_query.Role =  tb_MA.Team 
WHERE (((history_query.verantwortlich) IN (Select [MA-Kennung] from tb_MA 
where team = '10  ENG-PL')))
```

Based on my above query it returns me the follwoing output

```
ID   Verantwortlich             Role                           Error_text 

15      US1                   10 ENG-PL                           zxcv
10      US3                                                        xyz
```

Provide some Links where i can learn this type of query. I always stuck on this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer with this below query.

```
SELECT *
FROM history_query LEFT JOIN tb_MA ON history_query.verantwortlich =  tb_MA.Team
WHERE ( ((history_query.verantwortlich) IN (Select [MA-Kennung] from tb_MA where team = '10  ENG-PL') ) 
OR history_query.Role ='10  ENG-PL' OR   ((history_query.Role) IN (Select [MA-Kennung] from 
tb_MA where team = '10  ENG-PL') ) );
```

any other suggestion is welcome.